# copy a fifth (20%) of an int array in c

Tags: c, arrays, copy

I was trying to copy the first 20% of an int array into another one but every time I tried, the VS debugger showed this error:

Unhandled exception at 0x00DB592A in Anti Virus.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00B41000.

here is the code:

```
/*
regularStr - the full arr
regularLen - its size
mode - what part of the array (first 20% or last)
quickFileLen - a pointer to where to put the shorten array size
*/
int* stringToQuickStr(int* regularStr, int regularLen, int mode, int* quickFileLen)
{
    int i = 0, start = 0;
    *quickFileLen = (regularLen / 5);
    int* quickStr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (*quickFileLen));
    if (!(quickStr))
    {
        printf("quickStr calloc() ERROR!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (mode == FIRST_20)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < *quickFileLen; i++)
        {
            quickStr[i] = regularStr[i];
        }
    }
    return quickStr;
    free(quickStr);
}
```

the program was always crashing in the FIRST_20 copy after some copying.

Comment: `i` is of type `int`, while `quickFileLen` is a pointer to `int`.  Are you really comparing them in the for condition?

Comment: I copy the arrays in the place i

Comment: Show the call to `stringToQuickStr()` and the variable definitions

Comment: 'free(quickStr);' ??  Will never be executed, which is not a bad thing actually:)

Comment: fileStrQUICK = stringToQuickStr(fileStr, &fileLen, FIRST_20, &quickFileLen); do you mean this?

Comment: `&fileLen` is not compatible with `int`. Turn on your compiler warnings and **mind them**.

Comment: Note that they say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Use `fileLen` instead of `&fileLen` when you call the function.

Comment: You should return some other thing such as `NULL` on error because ​`-1` is not compatible with `int*`

Comment: @MikeCAT Yeah, this guy really doesn't grok the difference between pointers and integers.

Comment: @GuyShilman Please include the usage in your question by editing it.